# Operator << cannot be applied to operands of type long and long

Tags: c#, bit-shift

I am trying to use the `<<` operator on a `long`, like so:

```
((long) num3) << ( 2 + (long) num4)))
```

This gives me the following error:

> Operator << cannot be applied to operands of type long and long.

If I don't cast `num4` to a `long`, there is no error. However, I cannot keep it as an `int`. Is there any other way around this?

Comment: Do you really want `<<`, and not `<`?

Comment: Why are you casting to `long` in the operator anyways? Do the bit-shift and cast the result to `long`. Problem solved.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to shift a long by more than 64 bits, so the right hand operator doesn't need to be a long.

Comment: As @vcsjones said, `((long) num3) << ( 2 + num4)`

Comment: "sadly i can not keep it as an int": why? And anyway, what are you trying to do exactly?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The right operand has to be an `int`, not a `long`. It wouldn't make sense to use a `long` as the number of bits to shift, since integral types in C# never have more than 64 bits.

Comment: Uh, why the downvotes? Did I say anything wrong? Please comment when you downvote, so that I know what's wrong...

Comment: This is correct, not sure why anyone downvoted it. The C# spec basically says it in 7.9. "type of the second operand must always be int." with the assumption dynamic is not being used.

Comment: I didn't down vote.. but I would guess that what someone may not like about this answer, is its an answer without knowing why person asking the question said "I cannot keep it as an int." Hence the answer has lower chances of being the "appropriate" answer to original question.. even though it correctly states the facts. Just my theory.. I don't like it either, when anything is down voted without any comments.. so I am sharing one perspective which comes to mind.

Comment: to add to this: it makes sense that you would want to shift numbers by integer amounts. You could never shift a number of bits by a decimal number. Shifting a bit by .5 doesn't make sense. :-p

Comment: Why not use a byte then? It wouldn't make sense to use an int with that explanation.

Comment: @JPtheK9, true, but I'm not the one who designed the language and the runtime ;). The IL instruction [`shl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/weefc5ww.aspx) expects an int32 as the number of bits to shift.

Comment: Yeah. But you explained it.